# xslt substring question

Tags: xslt

I am new to XSLT.
I have a input XML file which needs to be shown as a different output XML. I am using the xslt for transformation.
 Input XML:

```
<Row>
<Column>abc.xyz.ijm</Column>
<Row>
```

Output XML:

```
<abc>
  <xyz>
    <ijm>String</ijm>
  </xyz>
</abc>
```

I tried using xsl:when along with substring-before and substring-after functions but the result xml is not close to what I want. 
How to know the last occurence of '.' so that `<ijm>String</ijm>` is constructed followed by the end tags of the words that are found before each of the previous occurences of the '.' so that `</xyz> and </abc>` can be added as shown in the output xml above?

Any code snippet **is not at all** appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Excellent question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short solution and extensive explanation. :)

Comment: I reversed my upvote for this question. Reason: **the user @joe doesn't accept answers** !, Anyone, take this into account and don't waste your time answering @joe 's questions.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="Column/text()" name="tokenize">
   <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
   <xsl:if test="string-length()">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not(contains($pText,'.'))">
        <xsl:element name="{$pText}">String</xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:element name="{substring-before($pText,'.')}">
          <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="pText"
              select="substring-after($pText,'.')"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be well-formed):

```
<Row>
    <Column>abc.xyz.ijm</Column>
</Row>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<abc>
   <xyz>
      <ijm>String</ijm>
   </xyz>
</abc>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **Recursively called named template** with stop condition: the `$pText` parameter is either the empty string or a string that doesn't contain the period character.
2. **Intermediate action**: Create an element whose name is the substring-before the '.' character, then call yourself recursively with the text after the first period character as parameter.
3. **Stop action**: Create an element with name  -- the whole string in the parameter, and value: the string `"String"`.

Comment: Thank you. It works great. It is now failing with XSL transform error saying - 'Expected QName error' when the Column value  contains [*]. The example is <Column>abc.xyz.events.event[*].date.value</Column>. Hope to know your input. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to tell us what output you want for that case. Also, if you want people to solve problems for you, it's considerate if you try to explain the whole problem at the start, rather than changing the requirements when you get a solution.

Comment: @joe: @Michael-Kay (Dr. Kay) is absolutely right that changing the definition of the problem after you receive correct answers is something you should not do. Please, ask a new question with your new requirements! The error you get is because *now* you have changed the data in your source XML document and there is a string between too periods that is not a syntactically valid XML name.

Comment: k. Thank you for your input and sorry for not being aware of the forums rules. Have a nice day.

Comment: @joe: At SO the way to say "thank you" is to accept the answer.